# How to properly exit a multi-threaded program

Tags: c#, multithreading, aforge

I made a program based on Aforge (it's a video library). This library creates its own refresh events for the next video frame from camera. So far so good, earlier people have helped me with multi threading so these Aforge threads could report back to the main program thread, again so far so good, it works great.

The code can be seen here: [how to do multithreading when using outside referenced code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966288/how-to-do-multithreading-when-using-outside-referenced-code).

But now I regularly notice a new program error. The problem starts when I want to exit the program. At the moment the Aforge thread might still be active. And it wants to write back to main form that is closed.

Somehow I need to stop the other thread before I close the program. There is an option in Aforge to do something like camera stop, but it's not enough. But then still my code wants to write on the main form that's already closing.

Is there a way to stop all threads, or some safe way to close from the originating thread? I even placed the back reporting to the main program in a try catch construction but it didn't work well, the only way of stopping it in these situations is to press the stop execution button within Visual Studio itself.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you may have an `Invoke` call about to happen on your form just as you've closed the form. I've had this happen as well.

What I've done is to set a "shutdown" variable when I start to close the form, and then use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` to watch for `InvalidOperationException` (or whatever you're getting), and ignore if shutdown is set.

Comment: It would be simpler (and probably more correct?) to use BeginInvoke instead of Invoke. Do you really need the worker thread to wait on the UI to finish whatever updating it did? Using BeginInvoke doesn't leave you with the orphaned Invoke call because it's just a PostMessage call whose message will not be removed from the message queue.

Comment: ...Of course BeginInvoke has a different (potential) problem: If the worker thread goes too fast for too long, BeginInvoke starts dropping calls (it has some number of maximum queue size). If the worker operates in bursts, or doesn't post too many calls this is not an issue. If it becomes one, then you have to find another way to throttle the worker.

Comment: Well since its an usb webcam, with its own frame rate, that shouldnt go faster then my calculation. But its all still beta draft, so for now my code is faster then my webcam.. but the camera may never go faster then my code, so in essence i'dd like my calculations to finish.
Anyway i will start reading about BeginInvoke in case i miss something. its a bit hard topic dough

Comment: @ jon B
I think thats what i want but, i find it difficult to understand what you write.

Comment: @user613326 start by using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`. Set a breakpoint or ouput a debug message when it fires. This will help you start to see how you can handle these errors when the program closes.

Comment: Maybe we dont understand each, i'm sure of the cause of the problem.
You wrote 

"What I've done is to set a "shutdown" variable when I start to close the form" 

I wonder the mechanism of how that works since when exit the program there is not much that can be done??