# Aforge for webcam

Tags: c#, aforge

I wrote a code for acessing the webcam with two buttons and a picture box

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Imaging;
using AForge.Imaging.Filters;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

namespace cam
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private FilterInfoCollection webcam;
    private VideoCaptureDevice cam;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webcam = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        foreach (FilterInfo VideoCaptureDevice in webcam)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(VideoCaptureDevice.Name);

        }
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
      }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cam = new VideoCaptureDevice(webcam[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        cam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cam_NewFrame);
        cam.Start();

    }
    void cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    }



    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cam.IsRunning)
        {
            cam.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    }



    }

 }
```

The code build up successfully. but on debugging the picture box is not working. start and stop is working properly. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try `pictureBox1.Invalidate()`.

Comment: could you please tell me how to save the image

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.save.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you have to delete first

```
Bitmap bitmap;
```

because its null and that what you show in picture box 
not the picture that come from camera

Answer (score 0):

a long time ago i had problems too with aforge but got it working 
see my code inhere : [How initialize AForge webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925021/how-initialize-aforge-webcam/12966093#12966093)