# Aforge Program works only on Debug mode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, aforge

am trying to make streaming video using aforge on visual studio windows forms
in debug mode everything works well but after publishing it the picturebox that is used to show the video still white
Here is the code

```
      if (device != null && cboDevice.Items.Count != 0)
        {
            if (firstim != null)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = firstim;
            }
            device = new VideoCaptureDevice(filter[cboDevice.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);

            device.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler( Device_NewFrame);
            device.Start();

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
          filter = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
          foreach(FilterInfo dev in filter)
        
            cboDevice.Items.Add(dev.Name);
            cboDevice.SelectedIndex = 0;
            device = new VideoCaptureDevice();

        
    }

   private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (device != null && cboDevice.Items.Count != 0)
        {
            
            device = new VideoCaptureDevice(filter[cboDevice.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);

            device.NewFrame += Device_NewFrame;
            device.Start();
```

}
}

Comment: You say it works fine in debug mode but not after releasing. Are you talking about running the Release build in Visual Studio or are you talking about after shipping your application?

Comment: Make sure formatting is correct: as is,it seems the Form_Load method is declared inside the first line if... That simply cannot compile.

Comment: no the code works fine but after shipping the application the picturebox doesn't seem to work

Comment: @BrahimAlayoud, If you want to use webcam to capture the screen picture, you can refer to [How initialize AForge webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925021/how-initialize-aforge-webcam).